# spamassassin filter for custom expression

Tags: spamassassin

I would like to add a rule that blocks all incoming e-mails that contain a certain expression. Ex: 'Test Phrase'. I have added the line
`rawbody        NO_SPAMW    /Test"  *"Phrase/i`
but it seems it doesn't work. Can you tell me what is the correct way to parse a space to spamassassin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match a `space` with `\s`.

```
rawbody TEST_PHRASE /test\s*phrase/i
score TEST_PHRASE 0.1
describe TEST_PHRASE This is a test
```

More about writing custom rules [here](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules)

Comment: I tried to add the rule but nothing happens. I am using spamassassin with mimedefang. After a lot of unsuccessful testing I've tried stopping spamassassin service, and used only mimedefang but without any result. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried this rule before answering here. I use SPamassassin with `spampd`. Hope this should help http://www.mickeyhill.com/mimedefang-howto/